# Are web pages hosted on a public domain (S3) vulnerable to OAuth 2.0 token theft via same-origin policy?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have a web page that uses JavaScript to access users' Gmail accounts through the Gmail API using OAuth 2.0, and I'd like to host the HTML and JS files on Amazon's S3 service.

For this reason, I've authorized https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ as one of the origin URIs in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)'s credential page. My page works great, but it has me wondering:

If my page shares the same origin URI as every other web page hosted on S3, wouldn't this mean that another page would satisfy the same-origin policy and be allowed access to my page's access tokens?

For example, say a user just granted my app access to his Gmail account. Google sees an approved origin URI and sends back an access token.

Now imagine some other page hosted on S3 had copied my app's Client ID (publicly stored as a variable in JS) and was repeatedly requesting for an access token from Google. Once my user grants that access to my page, won't the other page also receive the token from Google since it satisfies the same origin URI?

I realize one solution to this potential problem is to host my web page on a domain that I have control over, but I'm curious if that is the only way.

Comment: The more obvious way to avoid the potential problem seems like it would be to use the virtual url format for an S3 bucket, `https://bucket-name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/key` (substituting the appropriate region, or just "s3" for US-Standard) unless your bucket name has a dot in it... in which case, create a bucket name without a dot... no?

Comment: Good idea. That does work exactly how I had hoped S3 would and avoids any possible same-origin problems. Thank you!